# how to make drop down checkbox selected even i reload the page using Jquery and angular 4?

Tags: jquery, angular, checkbox, jquery-plugins

I am using angular 4 with integrated JQuery the form which contains drop down checkbox once the drop down field is selected should not be change  even if I reload the page or until I re select.

> **dropdown.html:**

```
<div class="chkdropdown">
          Show and Hide Columns
        <ul>
             <li>
               <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="name" id="col_2" />&nbsp;S NO&nbsp;                
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="name" id="col_3" />&nbsp;DrugName&nbsp;                
           </li>
           <li>
              <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="salary" id="col_4" />&nbsp; Generic Name&nbsp;                  
           </li>
           <li>
              <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="gender" id="col_5" />&nbsp;Generic Combination&nbsp;                    
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="city" id="col_6" />&nbsp;Dosage &nbsp;              
              </li>
              <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="email" id="col_7" />&nbsp;VAT &nbsp;               
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

> **ang.component.ts:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){                       
            $(".hidecol").click(function(){

                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split("_");
                var colno = splitid[1];
                var checked = true;                                        
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    checked = true;
                }else{
                    checked = false;
                }
                setTimeout(function(){
                    if(checked){
                        $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                        $('#drug_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                    } else{
                        $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                        $('#drug_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                    }

                }, 500);

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad this code in your jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//here i checked localstorage values
    var checkedvalues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkedvalues"));
    console.log(checkedvalues);
//created obj to store check values
    var someObj={};
    someObj.checked=[];
//looped through checkvalues from local storge ad add checked property to its values
    $.each(checkedvalues, function(key, value) {
      console.log(key,value);
      $("#" + value).prop('checked', value);
      console.log($("#" + value));
    });
                $(".hidecol").click(function(){

                    var id = this.id;
                    var splitid = id.split("_");
                    var colno = splitid[1];
                    var checked = true;                                        
                    if($(this).is(":checked")){
                        checked = true;
//push chekced values in above created array.
                        someObj.checked.push($(this).attr("id"));
                        console.log(someObj.checked);
//add same values in local storage.
                        localStorage.setItem("checkedvalues", JSON.stringify(someObj.checked));

                    }else{
                        checked = false;
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(checked){
                            $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                            $('#drug_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                        } else{
                            $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                            $('#drug_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                        }

                    }, 500);

                });
            });
```

and this in html

```
<div class="chkdropdown">
          Show and Hide Columns
        <ul>
             <li>
               <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="name" id="col_2" />&nbsp;S NO&nbsp;                
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="name" id="col_3" />&nbsp;DrugName&nbsp;                
           </li>
           <li>
              <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="salary" id="col_4" />&nbsp; Generic Name&nbsp;                  
           </li>
           <li>
              <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="gender" id="col_5" />&nbsp;Generic Combination&nbsp;                    
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="city" id="col_6" />&nbsp;Dosage &nbsp;              
              </li>
              <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol" value="email" id="col_7" />&nbsp;VAT &nbsp;               
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: i did as u given above but there is no change!!  i applied this code on ng onint jquery function..

Comment: check if values are properly setting in your local storage browser

Comment: follow the tutorial link which I have shared it should work as expected and very easy to integrate.

Comment: i  have the form which contains drop down checkbox once the drop down field is selected should not be changed even if I reload the page or until I re select  the boxes....

Comment: its very simple are you getting the values which are selected from checkbox? if yes just add the code below that line to set that values in local storage. and when the page reloads or on document.reload you call that local storage value from local storage. values should be {"option1":true,"option2":false,"option3":false}

Comment: error showing that  checked [ts] Property 'checked' does not exist on type '{}' its not available in var someObj={}....@hrishikes

Comment: on which line this is error is coming i have executed same code on jsfiddle it is working fine

Comment: var someObj={};
    someObj.checked=[];   in this line showing error

Comment: no the error would be in this line someObj.checked.push($(this).attr("id"));

as typescript is typesafe you need to use (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(elementId)) it is type error  i have done in proper jqeury if you used jsfiddle and copy paste this code it will work exactly . for typescritp you need to debug html events.

Comment: might be so you need to do same thing and logic. I don't know what the error is why it is coming. the process is same whether you do in typescript or javascript or jquery.

Comment: happy to hear that checkbox is working fine, what's the logic behind hide and show columns?

Comment: $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').hide(); and  $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').show();   this is my code for hide and show columns....

Comment: i dont find this #drug_table id in html

Comment: <table width="100%" id="drug_table"  border="0"  class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="tr_header">           
            <th> S.No </th>
            <th>Drug Name </th> </tr></thead></table>

Comment: just call your onclick function at the time of retrieving your local storage value

Comment: that function i wont click..because that drop down check box already been selected...when i reload the column those are selected in drop down box should be hidden even if i reload..

Comment: i am sorry but i am really not getting the logic behind this hide and show i tried extracting the value and pass this value to your colno and called the same function while getting this local storage.

Comment: i have understood I'm using your code in Angular 4 ngOnInit(){  your code here} when i click its working fine and column hidden but as i said u  i want the those column should be hidden based on the selected drop down check box when reload the page

Comment: so basically what you need is pass the same id which is selected by default to hide function.

Comment: yes..i need pass the same id which is selected by default to hide function .